# Estimating the age of a URL

Tags: url, caching, web, time, web-crawler

I have a collection of URLs that I want to estimate the age of. Let me phrase the question this way:

**How to estimate the earliest point in time in which querying a URL would be successful (let's say HTTP status code 200 for a GET request)?**

The solution I'm currently thinking about is perhaps Google (or some other crawler) has some (publicly available) way of providing the timestamp when they first visited that URL (preferably API).

I know how to get the age of Google's cached version, e.g.: [webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3astackoverflow.com). However, because the cached versions are updated rather frequently, this isn't very useful.

Comment: It would be useful for web analysis.

Comment: What do you mean? "Web analysis" is not really a meaningful phrase to me. Is there a specific task you're trying to accomplish? IMO, such a date/age just isn't terribly meaningful. Is this some sort of "internet tenure" measurement?

Comment: The only date of URL indexing makes sense for search engines. Date of 1st URL querying doesn't make sense at all, IMHO. I think you won't find such information.

Comment: @Oleg: Don't you think e.g. Google stores the timestamp of when they first crawled a page?

Comment: @MattBall: Yes, that's one thing you could do. However, my intent is to simply put a date on the *content* of a page. This would work in cases were you could assume the content (or featues of the content) hasn't changed since first published. Actually, it would be better to just ask for the first ever cached version of a page, but I assumed the date alone would be available with a higher probability than the whole page.

Comment: I'm sure that Google stores date when a page was indexed. And Google treats this date as date of page creation. I also think that Google doesn't stores date of 1st accessing, since it means nothing.

Comment: @Oleg: Ok. Well, let's just assume that Google indexes a site immediately after visiting it for the first time, so that the date of *their* first accessing and date of indexing is equal. This isn't the point anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible in a reliable way. (Well, unless you have all access log files of the servers you are interested in.)

Internet Archive’s [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) shows the first time it crawled a webpage. Of course it may take time until their bots find and crawl a page for the first time, so most indexed pages probably are much older.

Also note: as soon as the crawler is blocked (e.g., via *robots.txt*), the history/copies will be removed ([from the FAQ](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#The_Wayback_Machine)):

> When a URL has been excluded at direct owner request from being archived, that exclusion is retroactive and permanent.